# Ember.js - Hiding parent views in nested resources

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building a web video app that functions in a similar way to YouTube. My desired URL path is `appname.com/video-title/video-id`. I've represented it in this way:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('videos', { path: '/:video_title' }, function(){
    this.resource('video', { path: '/:video_id' });
  });
});
```

The problem that I'm having is that the `video-id` url is also displaying the `video-title` template.

The `video-title` url should display search results of that video name and the `video-id` url should display the specific video and play it in a video player.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="videos">
  <ul>
    {{#each video in model}}
      <li>{{video.title}} by {{video.author}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="videos">
  <p>{{title}}</p>
</script>
```

Model:

```
var videos = [{
  id: '1',
  title: 'Skiing in Tahoe',
  author: 'daniel'
},{
  id: '2',
  title: 'Exploring San Francisco',
  author: 'nickmillerza'
}];
```

I'm new to Ember - perhaps I shouldn't use it for an app like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can totally do this

```
App.VideoRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    // return model
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller) {
    // render it into the videos outlet
    this.render('videos', {controller: controller});
  }
});
```

Comment: I do this and it still shows the Videos template as well as the videos/index template!

Comment: @DanielvanderMerwe please check my edit, and the second template name in the posted code should be `video`. Possibly be a typo I suppose.

Comment: Yep thanks, I just figured it out. Appreciate the help.